# Angular version updation error - I have updated the angular version from 8 to the latest version

Tags: angular

I have updated the angular version.

after updation when I ran the project - ng serve

THe error is getting display -

An unhandled exception occurred: Script file ./node_modules/@sudhanshu/radial-indicator/radialIndicator.min.js does not exist.
See "C:\Users\A7704913\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-WWrqOL\angular-errors.log" for further details.

```
Package.json -

{
  "name": "angular-application",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod=true --output-path=../ui-src/META-INF/resources",
    "devwatch": "ng build --watch=true --prod=false --output-path=../ui-src/META-INF/resources",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "10.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "10.0.2",
    "@ant-design/icons-angular": "9.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
    "@sudhanshu/radial-indicator": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "ify-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jqwidgets-ng": "^9.1.6",
    "luxon": "^1.24.1",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^9.2.2",
    "ngx-tree-select": "^0.15.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.1.2",
    "rxjs": "6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.2",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.22",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to reinstall node modules?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the following steps. After performing the following steps, the error would be resolved.

**Steps to be followed:**

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. Delete package-lock.json file.
3. Run npm cache clean --force
4. Run npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have got the answer.

So after running **npm install** command I was getting the warnings and then I used to run the **npm audit fix** command after that ng serve. So I was getting the above mentioned error.

Therefor next time I ran first - npm install
Then -  npm start

This time I got no errors and I can able to see the project.